# jasperreports-core-renderer.jar jasper or ireport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We were on 4.1.3 jasper and are now moving to 6.2.0 of jasper

There were few other libraries in the lib, like jasperreports-core-renderer.jar

I am confused now. What does jasperreports-core-renderer.jar do?

I removed it and it works fine to render my reports.

Comment: I think that the using Maven will be a good idea in your case. You can easy control dependencies with it

Comment: Thanks for accept your question is on hold as to broad because of the title "what does it do"?... If you refrain question, to something like "is it needed " then probably the question can be reopen (ping me if you [edit] the question) otherwise just have fun...

Comment: What lib are you referring to? I assume maybe tomcat or jboss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jasperreports-core-renderer.jar` was not and is not part of the [jasper reports distribution](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.0)

It is part of iReport distribution and contains code for rendering xhtml (used by editor)

If you are not developing tool similar to iReport you can remove (and you should never have included) this library